# Which to use for OpenGL client side waiting: glGetSynciv vs. glClientWaitSync?

Tags: c++, opengl, video-streaming

I am unclear from the OpenGL Specification on [Sync objects](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sync.txt), whether to use `glGetSynciv` or `glClientWaitSync` in case I want to check for signalling of a sync object without waiting. How do the following two commands compare in terms of behavior and performance:

```
GLint syncStatus;
glGetSynciv(*sync, GL_SYNC_STATUS, sizeof(GLint), NULL, &syncStatus);
bool finished = syncStatus == GL_SIGNALED;
```

vs

```
bool finished = glClientWaitSync(*sync, 0 /*flags*/, 0 /*timeout*/) == ALREADY_SIGNALED;
```

Some details to the questions:

- Does `glGetSynciv` perform a roundtrip to the GL server?
- Is any method preferred in terms of driver support / bugs?
- Could either method deadlock or not return immediately?

Some context:

- This is for a video player, which is streaming images from a physical source to the GPU for rendering.
- One thread is streaming / continuously uploading textures and another thread renders them once they are finished uploading. Each render frame we are checking if the next texture has finished uploading. If it has, then we start rendering this new texture, otherwise continue to using the old texture.
- The decision is client side only and I do not want to wait at all, but quickly continue to render the correct texture.

Both methods have examples of people using them for the purpose of not waiting, but none seem to discuss the merits of using one or the other.

Comment: Interesting, although I doubt there will be much difference between the two usages.

Comment: A first test seems to indicate that glGetSynciv takes 0.01 ms, glClientWaitSync 0.001 ms (on NVIDIA, YMMV).

Comment: How did you get that kind of resolution?

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter is the way to go under Windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Right, but the timing data is missing some basic info, such as how you measured it and what the variance is.  You wouldn't want to just measure the timestamps before and after because it doesn't account for the effect the function could have on the performance of the entire frame (especially when we're involving multithreaded performance as in this case), and you wouldn't want to report a time without a sample variance, because it could be a fluke.

Comment: (Thinking out loud) Maybe `glGetSynciv` has to do more work? At least a switch dispatch plus the related parameter validation to check if the receiving buffer is big enough, plus a copy and not a return in a register...

Comment: Also, to really nitpick, remember that without a `glWaitSync` -- not `Client` ! -- and a re-`bind` of the object, you may not see the changes in a shared context. Cf. § 5.3.1 in the spec...

Comment: Incidentally, are these truly separate textures that you are switching between or are you simply constantly streaming in different LODs? Sparse textures (the [2nd version](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sparse_texture2.txt) in particular) would be a better approach to the latter; you can decide in your shader which LOD to use based on residency with no client synchronization of any sort.

Comment: Sparse array textures can handle the former case too, by the way. Assuming these textures have the same resolution.

Comment: This could be highly implementation dependent. I can't think of a good reason why they couldn't be optimized to perform the same. Since `glClientWaitSync()` looks like the more obvious API for the job, I wouldn't be surprised if it's more optimized.

Comment: @Andon-M-Coleman: We are streaming video images and try to achieve the low latency. Do you have a link to an example that uses spare (bindless?) texture arrays for video streaming?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I don't. Very little has been written on the subject so far, but it's a pretty key concept in the whole "Approaching Zero Driver Overhead" initiative. It's effectively tier two tiled resources, which is the D3D equivalent. I'd wager more will be written on the D3D concept, but it's still very new.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the Red Book,

> void glGetSynciv(GLsync sync, GLenum pname, GLsizei bufSize, GLsizei *lenght, GLint *values);
>
> Retrieves the properties of a sync object. sync specifies a handle to the *sync* object from wich to read the property specified by *pname*. *bufSize* is the size in bytes of the buffer whose address is given in *values*. *lenght* is the address of an integer variable that will receive the number of bytes written into *values*

While for `glClientWaitSync`:

> GLenum glClientWaitSync(GLsync sync, GLbitfields flags, GLuint64 timeout);
>
> Causes the client to wait for the *sync* object to become signaled.
>   **glClientWaitSync()** will wait at most *timeout* nanoseconds for the object to become signaled before generating a timeout. The *flags* parameter may be used to control flushing behavior of the command. Specifying GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT is equivalent to calling **glFlush()** before executing wait.

So, basically **glGetSynciv()** is used to know if the fence object has become signaled and **glClientWaitSync()** is used to wait until the fence object has become signaled.

If you only want to know if a fence object has become signaled, I would suggest using **glGetSynciv()**.
Obviously **glClientWaitSync()** *should* take longer to execute then **glGetSynciv()**, but I'm guessing.
Hope i helped you.

Comment: Well the important point is how glClientSyncWait with timeout 0 compares to glGetSynciv(). My tests seem to indicate that it is glClientWaitSync which is faster on NVIDIA. This makes me curious if glGetSynciv() has more drawbacks.

Comment: Yeah, I find it interesting that the function that should "wait" in fact runs faster then the one that should only retrieve OpenGL's state.

Comment: @MatthUnderpants It's not going to wait if a timeout of 0 is specified. That was the point of the question.

Comment: I understood what you meant, but it is a bad documented thing and it is as always implementation dependent.

Comment: FWIW - profiling suggests that `glClientWaitSync` is faster in this case than `glGetSynciv`, at least on recent Nvidia drivers.